# How to add new user for RDP access to service fabric cluster VMs?

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I have access to a azure service fabric cluster, and need to login to the nodes to look at logs and other debugging information. How do I get hold of a username/pass in order to RDP in? I have Contributor level access to this subscription.

I have been poking around for an hour now, and the only thing I found was the admin username on the Virtual Machine Scale Set -> Operating System -> "Administrator User Name". But no pass (which is fine), or a way to add a new user either.

The ARM template also doesnt have anything useful.

Answer (score 1):

[Try the following](http://micahmckittrick.com/2017/05/17/how-to-reset-password-for-vmss-scale-set-instances/):

1) If Azure PowerShell is not installed, install it from http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/downloads/

2) Open up PowerShell ISE as an Administrator
Paste the following script into the Window modifying each of the red portions accordingly:

```
Login-AzureRmAccount
Get-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionId ‘SUBSCRIPTIONID‘ | Select-AzureRmSubscription

$vmssName = ‘SCALESETNAME‘
$vmssResourceGroup = ‘SCALESETRESOURCEGROUP‘
$publicConfig = @{‘UserName’ = ‘USERNAME‘}
$privateConfig = @{‘Password’ = ‘NEWPASSWORD‘}
$extName = ‘VMAccessAgent’
$publisher = ‘Microsoft.Compute’
$vmss = Get-AzureRmVmss -ResourceGroupName $vmssResourceGroup -VMScaleSetName $vmssName
$vmss = Add-AzureRmVmssExtension -VirtualMachineScaleSet $vmss -Name $extName -Publisher $publisher -Setting $publicConfig -ProtectedSetting $privateConfig -Type $extName -TypeHandlerVersion ‘2.0’ -AutoUpgradeMinorVersion $true

Update-AzureRmVmss -ResourceGroupName $vmssResourceGroup -Name $vmssName -VirtualMachineScaleSet $vmss
```

3) Navigate to the Azure Portal and select the VM Scale Set
Select Instances
You should see that all the instances are not updated to the Latest Model

4) Check all the boxes of the instance you wish you update with the new username and password
Select Upgrade

5) After a few mins (Depending on the number of instances you updated) you should see the Latest Model change to Yes

6) Attempt to login to the node